# Java: ternary operator with single line if stmt

Tags: java

Could you help me to write efficient Java code.

The logic is:
I have to read the first valid record in a file and generate a file name. The invalid/valid records are identified by the first 2 chars of the line. Invalid record first 2 chars are populated in an ArrayList named ignoreTrans(passed as arguments).

There are 2 scenarios:-
Scenario 1: all the records in a file are valid in this case ignoreTrans will be empty
Scenario 2: File has invalid records where ignoreTrans is populated from the passed arguments.

I wanted to write a ternary operator like below:

```
FileName = ignoreTrans.isEmpty() ? getFileName(pos) : (if (!ignoreTrans.contains(line.substring(0,2))) getFieldName(pos));
```

This statement is erroring. Could you suggest how to use ternary with if.

Thank you,

Comment: Just use another ternary operator?

Comment: "ternary operator with single line if stmt" -> One question: why press the `if` in a single line?

Comment: The ternary operator works for expressions not for statements.

Comment: You have two conditions; what is the value of the expression when they are not matched?

Comment: Short answer: ternary operator is for monkeys.  use an if statement, it is about a million percent more obvious.

Comment: If `getFileName` and `getFieldName` were supposed to be the same, you only need to test one condition `!ignoreTrans.contains()` because when `ignoreTrans` is empty `ignoreTrans.contains()` is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
FileName = ignoreTrans.isEmpty() ? getFileName(pos) : !ignoreTrans.contains(line.substring(0,2))) ? getFieldName(pos) : "";
```

Just like how you can have a nested `if` structure, you can nest ternary operators too.

Comment: Code-only answers are genereally not dicouraged. You should add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @Turing85, I agree with you. I just edited my answer to give an explanatory note.

Comment: You may also add that you can nest a ternary operator in a ternary operator like you can nest if statements, but you can't nest a if statement in a ternary operator.